# My github repo does not accept some js files?

Tags: angular, github, jhipster

I installed a jhipster project.After that I want to upload my project to github but some files js files(jquery.js,angular.js and ui-swagger.js files) cannot be  uploaded.The other files are okey.I can see other files in my repo.

my .gitignore file contains these lines :

```
# Compiled class file
*.class
# Log file
*.log
# BlueJ files
*.ctxt
# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/
# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar
# virtual machine crash logs, see 
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*  
# Project Specific   
/target/www/**
/src/test/javascript/coverage/
/src/test/javascript/PhantomJS*/

# Node   
/node/
node_tmp/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log.*


# SASS   
.sass-cache/

# Eclipse   
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
 tmp/
 tmp/**/*
 *.tmp
 *.bak
 *.swp
 *~.nib
 local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath
.factorypath
/src/main/resources/rebel.xml

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/**

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# Intellij
.idea/
*.iml
*.iws
*.ipr
*.ids
*.orig
classes/


# Visual Studio Code   
.vscode/


# Maven   
/log/
/target/


# Gradle   
.gradle/
/build/


# Package Files   
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.db


# Windows   
# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini


# Mac OSX   
.DS_Store
.svn

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear on external disk
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes


# Directories  
/bin/
/deploy/


# Logs   
*.log


# Others   
*.class
*.*~
*~
.merge_file*


# Gradle Wrapper

!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

# Maven Wrapper
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar


# ESLint
.eslintcache
```

How can I solve that problem?Just 3 files cannot be uploaded.

Comment: Can you update the question with the contents of your .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you stage these files? Try `git add <file_name>` and then committing and pushing them to remote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked .gitignore file ? or run command to see which files are being tracked

> git ls-tree -r branchname --name-only

Comment: I installed my .gitignore file.I use intellij Idea to send files to github